# Running command as different user with sudo but without root session?

Tags: sudo

I am going through this [article](https://www.maketecheasier.com/differences-between-su-sudo-su-sudo-s-sudo-i/) and I am a bit confused if this will matter with i use `-s -i` together with `-u` flag. We have 2 users, one is our personal user, and one is the application user. We don't want to ssh with our application user directly as we will lose the audit logs of who logged in at what time. We are not allowed to use `su` at all so essentially we will have to run via `sudo -u` method. What we are doing now is

```
user-1@1.1.1.1 $ sudo -S -u app -i /bin/bash
app@1.1.1.1    $ run whatever command we want
```

So going through the article, does make a difference if we add a `-u` flag? Is the below command the only way or what would be the recommended way for running command without root session? Or even better to login which `source .bashrc` files

```
user-1@1.1.1.1 $ sudo -u app $COMMAND
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: You are probably doing something wrong if you need an interactive session in the first place.

Comment: so the envvars configured on .bashrc/.bash_profile such as for $PATH, there is no ways to use them? I will have to use absolute path to trigger the scripts then?

Comment: If the account is never really used for actual interactive sessions, putting stuff there is a nice shorthand. In general, a common arrangement is to put the settings in a separate file and then `source` that from your `.bash_profile` for interactive use, and from the other place when you need those settings for a `cron` job etc.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.